# New theme/magento install - Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object

Tags: layout, error, theme, magento-1.6

I have recently set up a test server with magento 1.6 files copied from the live server, after getting it to work I uploaded the new theme files via FTP that I wanted to work with, with cache/compiler disabled etc.

Upon having installed it, and login back into magento back-end, I enabled to new theme package in system > config > design and imported the themes static blocks / CMS pages, and cleared cache just to make sure..

Now I am getting a blank page on my website except for this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /data/sportnor/public_html/multifitness.dk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 529

I've done some research now on the error message, and the fix that seems to have worked for many people doesn't seem like an option for myself, since `page.xml` is not present in:

```
\app\design\frontend\default\themename\layout\
```

Can someone please help me to identify as to what the problem might be? I've tried several things, problem still persists, if the information given is too vague, please let me know and I will provide with whatever I can.

Quick info:

Theme is "Ultimo"
Magento version 1.6.1.0
Currently hooked up to a DB with many products
All modules disabled /caching/compiler too etc.

Comment: I suggest adding a `var_dump($this);die();` there. Then at least you will know the class. Which will give you an idea where too look. I think somewhere in the `/themename/layout/*.xml` a type attribute is missing or set incorrectly.